# SonarQube for JavaScript

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, software-quality

Is there any way to get the /js files test report on `http://localhost:9000/`? I am using `mvn sonar:sonar` command to test my java plugins, But using this way i'm not able to get the JavaScript test report on local host. I have added sonar-javaScript-plugin under `\extensions\plugins` folder.

Comment: Do you want test execution report or coverage report? Can you please give more details on what you already tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in the past in the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
    <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.exclusions>src/main/content/plugins/**</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```